# I'm making a small refrigerator with a Peltier module but I can't find a heatsink. Will it work if I only use thermal paste and don't use a heatsink?

Tags: voltage, heatsink, peltier

I'm making a small refrigerator with a Peltier module but I can't find a heatsink.

- Will it work if I only use thermal paste and don't use a heatsink?
- Can I use a 9 volt battery for a 12 volt module?

Comment: How is thermal paste going to improve the heat transfer to air?

Comment: get a big surplus CPU heatsink with grease. Both are critical to it working well.

Comment: Yes it will work even without thermal paste, however it will work **very poorly**. It might work so poorly that you damage the peltier element while getting almost no cooling whatsoever. Go have a look at a video Julian Ilett made when he experimented with a Peltier element: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-a7iWbFtNg  Note how he uses a large heatsink and even then there isn't that much cooling capacity. Also learn (from the video perhaps) how a peltier element works and that the heatsink is **required** to get rid of the excess heat.

Comment: A 9V battery very probably does not have enough capacity for your Peltier. You did not state the current requirements of your Peltier, but most require multiple Amperes which a 9V battery can't provide.

Comment: If by "9 volt battery" you mean a PP3 battery, that will not last very long at all, maybe 10 minutes.

Comment: In my comment I didn't take into account that you want to use a 9 V battery. The 9 V battery has so little energy stored that the heatsink isn't needed but the peltier element also will not be doing anything useful as the battery will be depleted well before that. **this will simply not work**. Your project isn't going to work like this! You need a heatsink and you need a mains power supply. Search for similar projects other people did and do the same. If you stick to your plan your project will **fail**. It is guaranteed.

Comment: In other words: Learn what the heatsink *does*

Comment: Can you find a *really big* lump of aluminium? Or even an old central heating radiator? If so, just call it a heatsink...

Answer (score 1):

The Peltier module works by creating a thermal gradient when current is pumped into it. One side will get hotter than the other. The Peltier's heatsink removes hot-side heat to the air.

In this, the Peltier is just like an air conditioning unit with the (cold) evaporator and (hot) condenser. You've no doubt noticed that the A/C unit coils have fins on them: these improve thermal transfer.

So it goes with the Peltier: heatsink fins on the hot side allow it to radiate more heat. The bigger the sink, the more heat can be shed, and the more efficient the cooler can be.

What does thermal grease *do*, then? Without a heatsink, nothing. Its job is to improve the thermal contact to the heatsink and make it more efficient. No heatsink, no effect.

Can you run the Peltier module on 9V? That depends on the device. Can you run it on a 'transistor' 9V battery (a "PPE" or "E" type?) No, not nearly enough current.

Two more things:

- Consider adding a fan to the hot-side heatsink.
- Add a heatsink the the *cold* side too, to improve thermal transfer.

How can you make a heatsink? Extruded heatsink material is relatively easy to source, check with an electronics distributor.

You might even be able to source a suitable heatsink from scrap electronics, like an obsolete CPU motherboard or a graphics card. (Bonus: the heatsink likely would have a fan on it too.)